# adding my own images to a template

Tags: magento2

I want to add an image to a template.

I've put the image in the `/app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/web/images` folder.

Then I attempted several ways to try to reference/write the path in my template. After which I did System -> Cache Management -> Flush Static Files

1. Q1. Is that folder the correct place to put the image?
2. Q2. how do I refer to/write the path to the image in a phtml template?

I've obviously tried several variations to no avail. I also cannot find this information in the Frontend Developer's Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/your-imagenmae'); ?>
```

Answer 1: yes, This is `/app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/web/images` correct path

Answer 2: use above code add your image name instead of "your-imagenmae".

Comment: Many thanks for an eminently simple answer Prashant. This solution works..

Comment: If it helps you mark as accepted

Comment: How do I do that? I clicked the up arrow but it said I don't have enough credit or something :)

Answer (score 1):

Image folder correct path,
You have just missing your module path, ex. **Magento_Theme**
    app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/{Package_Module}/web/images/

Just add below code,
Ex. **loader.gif** image inside,

```
app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/{Package_Module}/web/images/loader.gif
```

You can get image url like below,

```
<?php $imageUrl = $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader.gif');  ?>
```

You can set inside image,

```
<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>"  alt="no-image" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rakesh. I haven't tested it because Prashant's answer (below) is simpler and works. Many thanks though.